# Graphql: Must provide query string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, relay

I have a simple express graphql server:

```
const schema = require('./schema');
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP(req => {
  return ({
  schema,
  pretty: true,
  })
}));

const server = app.listen(9000, err => {
  if (err) { return err; }
  console.log(`GraphQL server running on http://localhost:${9000}/graphql`);
});
```

And my request looks like:

[image]

**Any help?**

(Please don't close it as duplicate because the other post does not provide enough info on how the user solved it)

Comment: Try replacing `schema,` with `schema: schema,`

Comment: @ChrisG it would have throw Syntax error, if it didnt understand the syntax.

Comment: @ChrisG In ES6 `{ schema }` is equivalent to `{ schema: schema }`. It's syntactic sugar! Good eye, though: this looks like a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `application/json` in your Content-Type header -- you currently have `text/plain`. You've included the body parser middleware on the server, but it relies on that header in your request to know when it needs to actually parse the response into JSON.

Comment: and exactly how do you do this?